# Why is Claws Mail starting in offline mode?

Tags: 11.10, email, claws

I am sorry if this is not the best place to ask this, but hopefully someone might be able to help. After I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 from 11.04, Claws Mail 3.7.10 began starting in offline mode. It continues to do so upon every startup. I have searched and searched but cannot find any option that might affect this. Am I overlooking the option? Is this a bug with the current versions of Claws Mail and Ubuntu? Or is there some other way to fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's an issue w/NetworkManager, which seems to have more than its share of issues in 11.10.

As a workaround, edit your ~/.claws-mail/clawsrc file and set 'use_networkmanager=0'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem since I configured my network in the "traditional" way with `/etc/network/interfaces`, with a static IP. The workaround via clawsrc works for me, but I still had the problem that Pidgin did not want to connect anymore. So I just did:

```bash
aptitude remove --purge network-manager
```

Which should be ok on a stationary system. This also fixed Pidgin.